# Android app crashing on botton click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My activity has three buttons each when clicked leads to three activities respectively. The first two buttons are working perfectly but on clicking the third button the app crashes. The gradle syncs perfectly. The manifest is updated. Can someone point out how to sort this problem.

**Activity**

```
package com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by kishore on 01-Jun-17.
 */

public class Choice03 extends MainActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choice03);

        Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt10);
        Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt11);
        Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt12);

        button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent10 = new Intent(Choice03.this,choice1103.class);
                startActivity(intent10);
                finish();

            }
        });

        button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent11 = new Intent(Choice03.this,Choice1203.class);
                startActivity(intent11);
                finish();

            }
        });


        button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent12 = new Intent(Choice03.this,Choice1303.class);
                startActivity(intent12);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/choice_03_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

                    >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bt10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                        android:text="@string/choice_1_1"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bt11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                        android:text="@string/choice_1_2"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bt12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                        android:text="@string/choice_1_3"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>




    </LinearLayout>
```

**Target Activity**

```
package com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by kishore on 07-Jun-17.
 */

public class Choice1303 extends MainActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choice1303);

        Button button19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt19);
        Button button20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt20);
        Button button21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt15);

        button19.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent13 = new Intent(Choice1303.this,Choicedeffr1303.class);
                startActivity(intent13);
                finish();

            }
        });

        button20.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent20 = new Intent(Choice1303.this,Choiceecofr1303.class);
                startActivity(intent20);
                finish();

            }
        });

        button21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent21 = new Intent(Choice1303.this,Choiceadmfr1303.class);
                startActivity(intent21);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor">

    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">






        <activity
            android:name="com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Choice01"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Choiceadmfr1202"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Choice02"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Choice03"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".choice11"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Choice12"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Choice13"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Choice1303"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".choice1102"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".choice1103"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat.

```
07-26 18:30:41.652 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor D/OpenGLRenderer: drawRect multiDraw AppCompatButton @42251360 paint 0x61f2b268 id 5 style 0 AA 0 color 0xffffffff
07-26 18:30:41.653 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x617463a8>
07-26 18:30:44.508 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor I/View: Touch down dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{422526a0 VFED..C. ........ 0,196-656,344 #7f0c0062 app:id/bt12}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=326.50208, y[0]=58.171753, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=16574142, downTime=16574142, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
07-26 18:30:44.662 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor I/View: Touch up dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{422526a0 VFED..C. ...p.... 0,196-656,344 #7f0c0062 app:id/bt12}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=326.50208, y[0]=58.171753, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=16574293, downTime=16574142, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
07-26 18:30:44.663 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor V/Provider/Settings:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
07-26 18:30:44.681 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{4223c838 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4223be98 {com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor.Choice03}}
07-26 18:30:44.687 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@4223be98
07-26 18:30:44.931 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-26 18:30:44.931 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4193fcf8)
07-26 18:30:44.931 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
07-26 18:30:44.931 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor.Choice1303}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 18:30:44.932 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
07-26 18:30:44.932 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-26 18:30:44.933 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
07-26 18:30:44.934 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
07-26 18:30:44.934 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 18:30:44.934 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 18:30:45.039 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor.Choice1303.onCreate(Choice1303.java:43)
07-26 18:30:45.040 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
07-26 18:30:45.040 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
07-26 18:30:45.040 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
07-26 18:30:45.040 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/System.err:    ... 11 more
07-26 18:30:45.040 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
07-26 18:30:45.055 13842-13842/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor, PID: 13842
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor/com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor.Choice1303}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at com.kiginfotech.choiceofemperor.Choice1303.onCreate(Choice1303.java:43)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your logcat with the stacktrace.

Comment: What error you are getting. Post logcat herr

Comment: share your exception

Comment: Logcat is added @MuratK.

Comment: The app gets crashed when I click the third button. Logcat is added. Sry for the delay @PallaviTapkir

Comment: Logcat is added @gurkankesgin

Comment: Button button21 = (Button) findViewById(**R.id.bt15**) change it

Answer (score 0):

Add id to this button 15 ....you are referencing button R.id.bt15 for Button21

```
<Button
          android:id="@+id/bt15"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/background_light"
          android:text="@string/improve_administration"
          android:textSize="20sp"
                            />
```

Comment: But thats not the main xml. My problem is with the third button in main xml

Comment: Please name your files accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Button with id 15 does not exists in your target XML.

You should give the button below bt20 the id bt21:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt21"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:text="@string/improve_administration"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

And replace the following

```
Button button21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt15);
```

with

```
Button button21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt21);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing two different xml layouts

MainActivity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.choice03);
```

Choice1303:

```
setContentView(R.layout.choice1303);
```

You need to make sure you are either using the same xml file or make the same element id are in both xml files.